# Unexpected return value

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I'm trying to implement password comparison. First I tried this:

```
@Autowired
private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

@Autowired
private OldPasswordsService oldPasswordsService;

Optional<OldPasswords> list = oldPasswordsService.findEncryptedPassword(passwordEncoder.encode("new password entered form web reset form"));
            OldPasswords value = list.get();
            boolean matches = passwordEncoder.matches("new password entered form web reset form", value.getEncryptedPassword());

            if (matches)
            {
                return new ResponseEntity<>("PASSWORD_ALREADY_USED", HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
            }
            else
            {
                OldPasswords oldPasswords = new OldPasswords();
                oldPasswords.setEncryptedPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(resetDTO.getPassword()));
                oldPasswords.setCreatedAt(LocalDateTime.now());
                oldPasswordsService.save(oldPasswords);
            }
```

Table for old passwords:

```
@Table(name = "old_passwords")
public class OldPasswords implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "encrypted_password", length = 255)
    private String encryptedPassword;
```

I tried to implement this:

```
......
return this.userService.findByLogin(resetDTO.getName()).map(user -> {
            Optional<OldPasswords> list = oldPasswordsService.findEncryptedPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(resetDTO.getPassword()));
            list.ifPresent(value -> {
                boolean matches = passwordEncoder.matches(resetDTO.getPassword(), value.getEncryptedPassword());
                if (matches) {
                    return new ResponseEntity<>("PASSWORD_ALREADY_USED", HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
                }
            }).orElse(() -> {
                OldPasswords oldPasswords = new OldPasswords();
                oldPasswords.setEncryptedPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(resetDTO.getPassword()));
                oldPasswordsService.save(oldPasswords);
            });
         return ok().build();

}).orElseGet(() -> notFound().build());
}
```

But I get for this line:

```
return new ResponseEntity<>("PASSWORD_ALREADY_USED", HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
```

Error

```
Unexpected return value
```

Do you know how I can fix this?

Comment: ..it is a syntax/compiler error ... `ResponseEntity<...>` is not the expected return type at this pont, but ...`void`!

Comment: Can you recommend me some solution, please?

Comment: ...1st: `list`is a very confusing variable name in this context! (but ok)

Comment: ..to solve the problem, *I* wouldn't "lambda too much", but just `dbResult.ifPresent() { /* ..do/return my things ..and ...*/ } else { return ... }` (calling `list` `dbResult`;)

Comment: ... can you show me code example, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It *is* probably `List`!
So with:

```
@Autowired
private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

@Autowired
private OldPasswordsService oldPasswordsService;
```

...and

```
@Autowired
private UserXXXService userService;
```

...let's assume, you are trying to actually:

```
@RequestMapping(...)
public ResponseEntity<String> resetPassword(ResetPasswordDTO dto) {
    ...
```

...that's how i would probalby go about it:

```
    final Optional<User> user = this.userService.findByLogin(dto.getName()); // Optional or null?, let's assume Optional
    // if user (login) exists:
    if(user.isPresent()) {
        // check old passwords, the method name/data structure lets assume it's rather List than Optional:
       java.util.List<OldPasswords> list = oldPasswordsService.findEncryptedPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(dto.getPassword()));
       if(list.isEmpty()) {// list is empty...
           // do your things..
           OldPasswords oP= new OldPasswords();
           oP.setEncryptedPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(dto.getPassword()));
           oldPasswordsService.save(oP);
           return ResonseEntity.ok().build(); // ok!
       } else {// otherwise:
           return new ResponseEntity<>("PASSWORD_ALREADY_USED", HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
       }
    } else { // otherwise (user.login not exists)
        return ResponseEntity<>.notFound().build();
    }        
}
```

(nor tested nor compiled)

..one technical question/detail remains/hidden: I miss the "binding" of "user" and "old_password"... so, should it check the old passwords of one user or all?

---

The 1st one sounds more fair/correct: old passwords should be "user based":

```
@Entity
// some unique constraints, when you have..., would be nice
public class OldPasswords implements Serializable { // singular is better for entity/table names!
  ....
  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn("user_id") // if you don't want to map the entity (for some reasons), you should still map the "id".
  private User user;

  // getter/setter ...
}
```

...

(with least impact,) you could then:

```
public interface OldPasswordsRepository extends Repository<OldPasswords, Integer> { // <- Integer ???
    List<OldPasswords> findByUserAndEncryptedPassword(User user, String pwd); // to use that...
}
```

**EDIT**: To match against the last three passwords, @Peter, your datastructure needs (additionally to `user`) some "tweak" - like an `created` timestamp!;) (a better choice, than a "version/age column")

```
 @Column(nullable = false) // final + instantiation is suited here
 final Date created = new Date(); //long, LocalDateTime, DateTime... Timestamp, java.sql.Date... and many alternatives.
 // getter
```

..then you could (in the repository):

```
// untested!
List<OldPasswords> findTop3ByUserOrderByCreatedDesc(User user);
```

..and use it in the controller/service, like:

```
... // if user is present
List<OldPasswords> list = oldPasswordsRpository.findTop3ByUserOrderByCreatedDesc(user);

for(OldPasswords opw:list) {

 // compare opw to dto.getPasword if match: return "bad request"
}
// after that (no bad request), store new (& old) password... (everywhere relevant), 
// ...and when nothing fails: 
return ResponseEntity.ok().build();

// else: user not present -> return not found
```

Comment: It should check for one user. I have one additional question. Currently this implementation checks for one unique match for old password. Is it possible to check for repeating the last 3 passwords?

Comment: I'm confused how the `created` timestamp can help me to detect for example if used has used last 3 times during the last month the same password again.

Comment: I tried your code proposal but it's not working. The old password can be still used.

Comment: it's not "working code" ..it's an outline, i hope you get me, thx for accept

Comment: `created` timestamp enables to order your data structure "chronologically" ...which makes it easier/possible to find the (chron.) last three entries. (`findTop3...`)